# Dependency Injection + WPF causes error during instantiation

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, vsto, simple-injector

Loading a WPF user control through DI causes the following error:

"The component 'Word.Addin.Presentation.MyTaskPane' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/Word.Addin.Presentation;component/mytaskpane.xaml'"

The user control is located in a separate assembly than the main project (word addin). If I create the control directly from within the addin (no DI) then there is no error.

I am using SimpleInjector for the DI container.  Here is the registration code:

```
            container.Register<MyTaskPane>();
```

Pretty simple as there are no contructor parameters (yet)...  the error occurs during the Initialize() method of the usercontrol.

**Update 1**

If I move the wpf user control(s) into the main (word addin) project the issue goes away.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: try using Activator.CreateInstance<MyTaskPanel>()     see the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator.createinstance)

Comment: Tried that voddy - didn't work either.  I think the reason was because my views were registered in a different assembly and I didn't tell VSTOContrib that. It was looking for the xaml in the root project.